# jQuery: focusout triggering before onclick for Ajax suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, triggers

I have a webpage I'm building where I need to be able to select 1-9 members via a dropdown, which then provides that many input fields to enter their name.  Each name field has a "suggestion" div below it where an ajax-fed member list is populated.  Each item in that list has an "onclick='setMember(a, b, c)'" field associated with it.  Once the input field loses focus we then validate (using ajax) that the input username returns exactly 1 database entry and set the field to that entry's text and an associated hidden memberId field to that one entry's id.

The problem is: when I click on the member name in the suggestion box the lose focus triggers and it attempts to validate a name which has multiple matches, thereby clearing it out.  I do want it to clear on invalid, but I don't want it to clear before the onclick of the suggestion box name.

Example:

[image]

In the example above Paul Smith would populate fine if there was only one name in the suggestion list when it lost focus, but if I tried clicking on Raphael's name in the suggestion area (that is: clicking the grey div) it would wipe out the input field first.

Here is the javascript, trimmed for brevity:

```
function memberList() {
    var count = document.getElementById('numMembers').value;
    var current = document.getElementById('listMembers').childNodes.length;
    if(count >= current) {
  for(var i=current; i<=count; i++) {
    var memberForm = document.createElement('div');
    memberForm.setAttribute('id', 'member'+i);
    var memberInput = document.createElement('input');
    memberInput.setAttribute('name', 'memberName'+i);
    memberInput.setAttribute('id', 'memberName'+i);
    memberInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    memberInput.setAttribute('class', 'ajax-member-load');
    memberInput.setAttribute('value', '');
    memberForm.appendChild(memberInput);
    // two other fields (the ones next to the member name) removed for brevity

    document.getElementById('listMembers').appendChild(memberForm);

  }
}
else if(count < current) {
   for(var i=(current-1); i>count; i--) {
       document.getElementById('listMembers').removeChild(document.getElementById('listMembers').lastChild);
   }
}

jQuery('.ajax-member-load').each(function() {
var num = this.id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');

// Update suggestion list on key release
jQuery(this).keyup(function(event) {
    update(num);
});

// Check for only one suggestion and either populate it or clear it
jQuery(this).focusout(function(event) {
  var number = this.id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
  memberCheck(number);
  jQuery('#member'+number+'suggestions').html("");
});
  });

}

    // Looks up suggestions according to the partially input member name
function update(memberNumber) {

  // AJAX code here, removed for brevity

  self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
              document.getElementById('member'+memberNumber+'suggestions').innerHTML = self.xmlHttpReq.responseText;
    }
  }
} 

// Looks up the member by name, via ajax
// if exactly 1 match, it fills in the name and id
// otherwise the name comes back blank and the id is 0
function memberCheck(number) {

   // AJAX code here, removed for brevity

    if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
          var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
          jQuery("#member"+number+"id").val(jsonResponse.id);
          jQuery('#memberName'+number).val(jsonResponse.name);
    }
  }
}
function setMember(memberId, name, listNumber) {
   jQuery("#memberName"+listNumber).val(name);
   jQuery("#member"+listNumber+"id").val(memberId);
   jQuery("#member"+listNumber+"suggestions").html("");
}

// Generate members form
memberList();
```

The suggestion divs (which are now being deleted before their onclicks and trigger) simply look like this:

```
<div onclick='setMember(123, "Raphael Jordan", 2)'>Raphael Jordan</div>
<div onclick='setMember(450, "Chris Raptson", 2)'>Chris Raptson</div>
```

Does anyone have any clue how I can solve this priority problem?  I'm sure I can't be the first one with this issue, but I can't figure out what to search for to find similar questions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use mousedown instead of click on the suggestions binding, it will occur before the blur of the input. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EDx82/).

```
<input type="text" />
<a href="#">Click</a>

$('input').on('blur', function(e) {
   console.log(e);
});

$('a').on('mousedown', function(e) {
   console.log(e); 
});
```

Or more specifically to your case:

```
<div onmousedown='setMember(123, "Raphael Jordan", 2)'>Raphael Jordan</div>
```

Comment: Simple and works, thank you very much!

As I'm fairly new to advanced Javascript and jQuery, do you know of any "function priority" lists?  It would help to have a reference which says onmousedown>focusout=blur>onclick, for example.

Comment: I don't know of any global list of all event types and scenarios and the order in which events would be fired. I know it's fairly easy to find references on the order of mouse/keyboard events but those don't typically (ever?) involve the relation of focus state.

Answer (score 0):

using onmousedown instead of onclick will call focusout event but in onmousedown event handler you can use event.preventDefault() to avoid loosing focus. This will be useful for password fields where you dont want to loose focus on input field on click of Eye icon to show/hide password